# Divergent electric potential

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, conductors, coulombs-law

Consider the electric potential at the rim of a uniformly charged ring/circle of radius $a$ (not a 2D disk) with linear charge density $\lambda$.

Take the origin as the centre of a the ring.
$$dV=\frac{kdq}{|\boldsymbol{r'-r}|}=\frac{k\lambda ad\theta}{\sqrt{a^2+a^2-2a^2cos(\theta)}}$$
$$V=\int dV=\frac{k\lambda}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{sin(\theta/2)}=k \lambda\int_0^{\pi}csc(u)du \to divergent$$
Why is this so? I can't understand this intuitively, or have I made an error in my calculation?

Comment: The electric potential and electric field at any infinitely thin line charge (not just a ring shaped one) goes to infinity. To give finite field one must have a finite surface charge density.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming an infinitely thin wire. This is unphysical. The potential at the surface of a wire of radius $a$ will have a  $\ln a$ contribution   --- just  as it is is outside  a long thin straight wire where
$$
V(r)= -\frac{\lambda}{2\pi} \ln (r/r_0). 
$$
(Here $r_0$ is the point at which we set $V=0$) Thus, at the surface
$$
V(a)= -\frac{\lambda}{2\pi} \ln (a/r_0).
$$
You get the same log dependence in computing the self inductance of a current loop

Comment: Thanks. For an infinitely long wire is $V=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{kdq}{r}$ not applicable as it seems to diverge?  and that $V=-\int_{O \neq \infty}^\boldsymbol{r} \boldsymbol{E} \cdot d\boldsymbol{r}$ is the only way to go?